# FIrebase Google auth operation not supported in this environment

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am working on ionic and firebase project, made a login page to sign in with google. I am using this Below.

```
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function (result) {
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
            $state.go('app.homepage');
        }).catch(function (error) {
        });

        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function (result) {
            if (result.credential) {
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            }
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
        }).catch(function (error) {
        });
```

When I run it in the browser it is working fine, but when I run it in android device I am getting auth/operation-not-supported-in-this environment.
The application is running on "location.protocol".
I researched a bit but could not find an exact answer. What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

popup and redirect operations are not currently supported in Ionic/Cordova environment. As a a fallback you can you an oauth cordova plugin to obtain a google/facebook OAuth access token and then sign in the user via signInWithCredential. Check this thread for more on this:

auth.signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbAccessToken));

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/facebook$20cordova/firebase-talk/mC_MlLNCWnI/DqN_8AuCBQAJ

Comment: Hi, I understood the situation but have certain question.
Can I use http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/
this plug in to get the facebook access token ?
Also in my facebook application page, should i put the platform mobile or a website? I am working with ionic

Comment: Hey Missak, Firebase does not recommend any specific cordova plugin for  obtaining the OAuth access token. Eventually, equivalent signInWithPopup should be supported directly in the web SDK for Ionic/Cordova. So this is more of a temporary solution until that feature is provided.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following because local storage is not enabled in webView, which is required for firebase

webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);