# Firebase: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error when trying to sign in with Twitter using Firebase. So I have seen that you can't use redirect or popup with React Native. My code is below and then there is some code that I think I should be implementing instead that lets you sign in with a credential but not exactly sure how specifically.

[image]

```
export function handleAuthWithFirebase () {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(authenticating())

        console.log('Loggin in')
        twitterProvider;
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(twitterProvider);
        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
            if (result.credential) {
                // This gives you a the Twitter OAuth 1.0 Access Token and Secret.
                // You can use these server side with your app's credentials to access the Twitter API.
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                var secret = result.credential.secret;
                // ...
            }
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
            console.log(user);

            // Get user info an set user in /users/ path
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            var email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

I see that I can sign-in manually using the following code

```
var credential = firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credential(token,secret);

firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
```

But how and when do I get the token and secret? I guess I'm confused on how to implement the sign-in manually. What part of my existing code do I keep and what do I get rid of? Has anyone done this before and has a code snippet by chance? Or can point me to a link? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621305/firebase-google-auth-operation-not-supported-in-this-environment

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not seeing any directly related to Twitter :( I get that I'm supposed to implement the sign-in manually but not quite sure how specifically. I've updated the question as well.